# Kusto query map through array

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm trying to map through Kusto dynamic array but I can't seem to find a specific function that can be used in Kusto's library function.

Here's my attempt so far:

```
let ArrayMap = (arr: dynamic) {
    range x from 0 to array_length(arr) - 1 step 1
    | summarize x = make_list(strcat('--', arr[x], '--'))
};
ArrayMap(dynamic(["a", "b", "c"]))
```

The problem with my attempt is that I am getting a table as the returned result instead of a dynamic array. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please share some context. I'm guessing you are not planning to run this processing over a single value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your table to a scalar.

```
let ArrayMap = (arr: dynamic) {
    toscalar (
    range x from 0 to array_length(arr) - 1 step 1
    | summarize x = make_list(strcat('--', arr[x], '--'))
    )
};
print(ArrayMap(dynamic(["a", "b", "c"])))
```

Comment: Thank you! My god, I feel like an idiot after spending about an hour.

Comment: Very cumbersome syntax. There are better solutions for this.

Comment: Hi @DavidדודוMarkovitz please share the simpler version. I would appreciate it!

Comment: As I wrote in the the comment to your post, I need some context. It feels like what you are asking for is just a friction of the use-case. This solution depends on the additional info.